# Best way to change between servers in iOS developerment

Tags: ios, xcode, server

We have different environments with different servers such as:

- Production Environment with Production server.
- Staging Environment with Staging server.

The Quality engineer with me needs every time to change between environments so I've to build every time, So I'm asking about a nice way to make this operation smooth and without build every time.
Any Ideas :) ?

Comment: You could use different schemes for your App and set Environment variables like the url of your server.

Comment: I think there should be application named alpha which connects to alpha server and beta and Gamma..

Answer (score 3):

If you have a "settings" page, add an entry in the DEBUG version that lets you change which server to use.

Or have two targets, one for staging and one for production server.

Comment: I've used both approaches.I would go with the "settings" page, using multiple targets can be a pain in the back (you have to tick those checkboxes each time you add a file...)

Answer (score 2):

One of the best ways to do is to create a ServiceEnvironment.plist that contains the endpoints to the various services. Each dictionary points to a specific configuration. At app launch you put up a action alert that allows the tester to choose the environment.  Then all endpoints should be obtained from the selected environment. You can also use the Settings preference bundle to set the environment.

```
[ServerEnvironment showAvailableConfigsWithCompletionHandler:^(UInt32 selectedConfigIndex) {
     [ServerEnvironment setCurrentConfig:servers[selectedConfigIndex]];
}];
```

You could use a alert or action alert and in the alert completion handler find out which button was clicked and use it as an index into the `servers` array to get the endpoints dictionary. Then use `[ServerEnvironment currentConfig]` at all places where you would get the endpoint. 
E.g. `[[ServerEnvironment currentConfig] objectForKey:@"loginWebService"]`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to set up different schemes for production, developement etc.

[image]

Then have each scheme depend on its own build configuration. In 'Build Settings' you can define constants under 'User-Defined' to use different configs depending on the current scheme you are using.

[image]

Btw, the DevServicesConfiguration and ServicesConfiguration entries are referring to .plist files with URLs etc. set up for each specific environment.

**EDIT**

'User-Defined' build settings can be included like shown in image:
[image]

Comment: There is no User-Defined section in Build settings page, can you explain more ?

Comment: @Abo3atef Oops! My bad.. I thought this entry was included in build settings by default. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In every answer given above you will need to rebuild the app. 
create a text file with word DEV read file programmatically at run time.

If that file contains DEV use DEV Base URL.

Every time environment needs to be changed just replace DEV with PROD in that text file

create function which will return either dev URL or Prod URL base on that txt file ....

Answer (score 0):

- Having a settings bundle which let Quality Engineer to point to any server would be a good approach.
- We need to map this settings bundle to a test specific scheme [different from release/production specific scheme].
- Also, we need to remove the settings bundle when releasing build. We can achieve that by adding a run script which removes settings bundle when scheme is not test specific scheme.

For detailed implementation, please refer this [article](https://medium.com/geekculture/distributing-configurable-ios-app-for-multiple-servers-using-configurations-schemes-and-settings-2e48460df18)